# GetProcAddress on NTDLL functions not working via ROP

Tags: windows, x86

This is somewhat convoluted, but I will try to focus on the heart of the issue. We are trying to do GetProcAddress on a few NTDLL functions, and it is not working. We are doing this via ROP and in a Windows 7 VM (Ultimate). We have seen sample code with the same APIs being called, but when we go look in EAX, there is a 0, not the runtime address of the function. We have used GetProcAddress successfully on numerous other functions via ROP - but for some reason it is not working with any NTDLL functions. We are supplying the correct handle to NTDLL, its base address. There are no problems there.

We are confused and lost as to why this is not working as intended. Is there some limitation we should be aware of? Is this hopeless? Are there any obvious issues we are missing?

Comment: which functions are you trying to get the address of? remember that they must be exported by the DLL for `GetProcAddress` to work.

Comment: Hi, the function in question that we were after was RtlCreateUserThread. But he tried another random NTDLL function like NtAllocateVirtualMemory, and the result was the same. The only one we care about is RtlCreateUserThread. Any insights?